# Implement Ajax in a Django Project not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to implement a like button to my blog post using Ajax, I am facing an error which I am unable to fix so I started from scratch more than once with the following steps:

1. Created Post model and Like model
2. Added the views which is currently working perfectly fine when I click like and unlike
3. I took the like section from the `post_detail.html` and added it in a separate html `like_section.html`
4. added the ajax with the correct values

Now my problem is that when I press the like button a new page is opened with ajax output

```
{"form": "....(html and ajax codes repeated)......"}
```

**My question is how do I fix this error so that I can submit a like without refreshing the page?**

**Here are the models for Posts.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ---------other attributed like: title, content, author, date_posted, slug-----
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Here are the views:**

```
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post)
        current_likes = post_obj.likes

        if user in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(user)
            current_likes = current_likes - 1

        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(user)
            current_likes = current_likes + 1

        post_obj.likes=current_likes
        post_obj.save()

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post)
        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value = 'Unlike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'
        like.save()
        context = {
            'post': post,
        }
    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html',context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

**Here is the post details.html**

```
        <!-- Like -->
        <div id="like-section">
        {% include 'blog/like_section.html' %}
        </div>
        <!-- Like -->
```

**Here are the like-section.html**

```
          <form action="{% url 'blog:like-post' %}" method="POST" class="like-form" id="{{post.id}}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value='{{post.id}}'>
            {% if user not in post.liked.all %}
              <button id="like" value='{{post.id}}' class="bwhite sm-button" style="color: grey; background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor:pointer; overflow: hidden; outline:none;">
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up" type="submit"></i>
              </button>
            {% else %}
              <button id="like" value='{{post.id}}' class="bwhite sm-button" >
                <i class="far fa-thumbs-up" type="submit"></i>
              </button>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="like-count{{post.id}}">{{ post.num_likes }} Likes</div>
          </form>
```

**Here is the ajax:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(event){
        $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var pk = $(this).attr('value');
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "blog:like-post" %}',
            data: {'post_id':pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
              $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
              console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
            },
            error: function(rs, e){
              console.log(rs.responseText);
            },
          });
        });
  </script>
```

**Here is the urls.py**

```
    path('blogs/like', like_post, name='like-post'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an HTML page as response from your view, I think that might be causing it. First just try returning something like {"msg","worked"} and see if its works

Comment: I added `return JsonResponse({'msg': 'worked'})` and I received `{"msg": "worked"} ` when I clicked like button

Comment: Why do you want to return to HTML page as a string in a Json response, Looks like that's causing the issue. Why don't you just return the number of likes that post has

Comment: when a user clicks the like button I don't want it to be refreshed, to show the difference so I am trying to return the like-section only and change from unliked to liked regardless of the number of likes

Comment: Yes, even for that you don't need to return the whole HTML page. In the response just return whether it's liked for the current user or not then update the button with JS based on the response. If you return the whole HTML page it will keep opening in a new page like it was happening before.